# postgres query for different tables

Tags: postgresql

I am new to postgres. I am trying to make the following query dynamic for different tables.

```
SELECT DISTINCT jsonb_object_keys(elements -> 'elements') AS individual_element
FROM Table1
```

I have 30 different tables on which I need to run this query but not sure how to do that in postgres (using pgAdmin4). Is this possible? Please help.

Thanks
-MS

Comment: If the table layout is all the same why 30 different tables?

Comment: If you want to use dynamic SQL, you must somewhere have a list of those 30 tables, right? Where is that list?

Comment: Yes, all the table structures are the same. I created a list of all the tables at public.tablelist.